# How to extract an image from an other using kinetic JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I have an image and I need to extract and create  another kinetic image from it (without modifying the original image).
The extracted image will be a rectangle, and I have the coordinates of its 4 points.
I checked on http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Image.html if there is any function that enables to do that but didn't find anything.

I tried with the crop method:

```
   var newImage = new Image();
   newImage.onload = function () {
   var roikImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 10,
            y: 100,
            image: this,
            width:100,
            heigth:100,
            crop: {
                x:0 , y:0 , width:100, heigth:100
            }

         });
    //Here I add the image to the layer, and draw the stage
         };
         newImage.src= 'src/of/my/image';
```

but I got a small portion of the image. I couldn't figure out how to do to crop the image using the coordinates of the 4 points of the rectangle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, than you are on the right track by using crop.

You can grab the image of another Kinetic Image by using the `.getImage()` function and then you can use the `crop` attribute or `setCrop()` and `getCrop()` methods to achieve what you want.

```
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 100,
            y: 50,
            image: imageObj,
            width: 106,
            height: 118
        });

        // add the shape to the layer
        layer.add(yoda);

        var newImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 300,
            y: 50,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            image: yoda.getImage(), //get the original image from yoda
            crop: {
                x:0 , y:0 , width:100, height:100
            }
        });

        layer.add(newImage);

        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(layer);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';
```

Change the **x,y** values inside `crop` to choose where you want to start the crop, and then set the **width and height** to the dimensions you would your crop size to be starting at the x,y point of the image. `x:0, y:0` is the top left corner of the image.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/R7pnK/)